# Trying to list AWS instances that older than X days, and their "Name" tag starts with a particular string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, json-query

I am trying to write a JMSEpath query to return a list of AWS EC2 instances that are older than X days and begin with a particular string.
Here's the command I am trying using the AWS CLI:

`` date +'%Y-%m-%d' --date="3 days ago" | xargs -I {} aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --filter Name=tag-key,Values=Name --query 'sort_by(Reservations[].Instances[[?Tags:Name!=`null`] | [(LaunchTime<=`2020-05-26` && (starts_with(Name, `startstring`) == `true`))]][].{KeyName: KeyName, Launched: LaunchTime,Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value}[], &Name )' --output table ``

I am able to get results when I only query for instances older than X days, but I am really struggling to figure out how to get it to return instances older than X days AND that begin with "startstring"

It's got to be something with my bracketing or how I'm referencing the values.
Thank you so much in advance for any help!